# Google Cloud Eventarc: Receive events via Pub/Sub directly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, event-arc

Eventarc uses Pub/Sub as a transport to deliver events to destinations like Cloud Run, HTTP endpoints, etc. But I want to consume the events directly from the Pub/Sub topic myself, ideally using a subscription I create myself.

Is there any way to make Eventarc just publish the events to a topic and stop there? Or, is there a way to directly tell an Eventarc provider to write to a topic, and not involve Eventarc itself?

It's clear in the Eventarc API documentation that you can specify the Pub/Sub topic to use as the transport. After doing that, I could read from the topic myself. The problem is that I am still required to specify a destination. Pub/Sub is not a valid destination in the API (although it is a valid provider).

Making a no-op Cloud Run to receive the events the way Eventarc wants to deliver them would work, but feels very silly (and costs money).

Comment: What's your event source?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm currently thinking of Firestore, but I'd like to do the same with others like Cloud SQL Postgres and Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native event are impossible to catch out of Eventarc.

A solution is to create a Cloud Run service with eventarc, and then to remove manually the pubsub subscription created and create yours (it's a hack)

If you use Audit log events, simply go to Cloud Logging, create your filter then sink the filter into a PubSub topic. And then create your subscription on that topic.